# One public key contains all subkeys?

Tags: key-management, pgp, gnupg

I've created a keypair with

```
gpg2 --gen-key
```

Then I created a subkey only for signing.

If I clearly understand the process I have now 3 pub/priv pairs. The master, one for encrypting and one for signing.

I exported public keys with:

```
gpg --armor --export FINGERPRINT > pub.asc
```

Now I have a file which seems to contain only one public key. Is it the master public key? Does this pub key contain the others public keys?

I'll sign with the third subkey I've created, so which public key do I need to upload on a keyserver?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subkeys are bound to the primary key and exported together with it when calling `gpg --export` or `gpg --send-keys`. Same applies to signatures and user ID packages.

Comment: Does this mean that the message will be encrypted once for each subkey, or that every subkey is able to decrypt a message encrypted for the original public key?

Comment: Neither of those; usually, GnuPG will encrypt for the _newest_ valid subkey. Only this subkey will be able to decrypt the message.